# Handle lifecycle event of Contact Picker activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, contacts, android-lifecycle, contactpicker

My application starts contact picker

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
 ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

I need to be able to detect if the Contact Picker loses focus without returning result to my activity( catching its onPause event would be fine).

Is there a way I can access activity lifecycle events if it is not declared in my manifes.(I tried registering `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` in my Application class but does not enter for events in ContactPicker).

Other way I can think of this is to create a custom contact picker, but that will be a lot of work.

Comment: Loses focus ? I think it will always return you a result.

Comment: onActivityResult will not be called if you press home button on the phone while in ContactsPicker. The activity will paused and you will be displayed the android home screen.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom contact picker.